# Explanation about operator precedence

Tags: algebra-precalculus

today i discovered that in Microsoft calculator Standard mode **4*3+4*3=48** . At least when you open History of calculations.

To me this is not acceptable, it is complete opposite from my complete 16 years of education, but apparently there are different kinds of people, seeing no problem with that. This formula is only correct if operator precedence is not followed.

This is part that i don't understand. Isn't modern math accepted and same in all around the world? Operations are associative and commutative? Or some different rules are applied in different countries?

I would appreciate some short explanation.
Thanks

[image: win10 calculator history]

Comment: To clarify "if operator precedence is not followed", the calculator interpreted the input as
$$
((4\times 3)+4)\times 3
$$

Comment: I wonder what operator precedence you would have to use for this to be correct.

Comment: You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1385549/81360) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/41252/81360) to be of interest.

Comment: @PinkPanther standard order of operations ("PEMDAS") would yield
$$
4 \times 3 + 4 \times 3 = (4 \times 3) + (4 \times 3) = 24
$$

Comment: I know that it should be 24. I was wondering how to come up with 48

Comment: You are right!  I didn't believe it so I tried it myself and got 48 instead of 24!  The calculator is doing the calculations serially rather than using operator precedence:  4*3= 12, 12+ 4= 16, and then 16*3= 48.Oddly enough the scientific mode does it correctly.

Comment: That's definitely an interesting discovery, Wow. Also, different countries don't have different rules -- that's impossible (well, they could try to come up with something different but it would most likely be wrong.). Different notation, maybe, but not different rules.

Comment: @N.Bar 
I am having some discusion on [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Lounge.aspx?msg=5639806#xx5639806xx) , so some answers really amazed me. I had to ask this silly question :D

Comment: My biggest problem with this is that Microsoft displays equation wrongly in calculation History. So when you want to check equation to see if you typed everything correctly, you still can have wrong result.

Comment: @miki You have to work with the memory of the calculator. But you´re right that the interpretation of the input is not state of the art.